# how to get list item value from RecyclerView Which is fetched from database?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have implemented interface and other required things but inside onClick method i stuck.

```
// this is inside ViewHolderClass that extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
     implements View.OnClickListener  //
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                 if (mOnClickListener != null) {
                     mOnClickListener.onListItemClick(v.getTag().toString(), getAdapterPosition());
                 }
```

In the place of tag value i want to get listItem value which user clicks.

More detail code:

```
    public class ScannerListAdapter  extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ScannerListAdapter.ScannerViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private Cursor mCursor;
// to store reference member variable is created
private final ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener;
// to initialize listener
public ScannerListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, 
   ListItemClickListener listener ) {
    mContext = context;
    mCursor = cursor;
    mOnClickListener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ScannerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
    viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scanner_list_item, parent, false);

    return new ScannerViewHolder(view);

}
```

code continue...

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ScannerViewHolder holder, int position) 
{
    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position))
        return;
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(1);
    values.add(2);



    String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ScannerEntry.COLUMN_SCANNED_RESULT));
    int id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ScannerEntry._ID));
    String date = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ScannerEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP));

    holder.resultTextView.setText(name);
 //        holder.itemView.setTag(key1,id);
    holder.dateTextView.setText(date);
//        holder.itemView.setTag(key2,name);
    holder.itemView.setTag(values);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCursor.getCount();
}

public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    // Always close the previous mCursor first
    if (mCursor != null) mCursor.close();
    mCursor = newCursor;
    if (newCursor != null) {
        // Force the RecyclerView to refresh
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

code continue...

```
    // inner class is created to hold the data of different views         
 class ScannerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
    View.OnClickListener {

    TextView dateTextView;
    TextView resultTextView;

    //method required to cast in itemView
    public ScannerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        dateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_textView);
        resultTextView = (TextView) 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.result_textView);

        // to  let view to invoke it
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 ArrayList<Integer> values = (ArrayList<Integer>) v.getTag();
   //        String value=v.getTag(2).toString();
                 if (mOnClickListener != null) {
                     mOnClickListener.onListItemClick(values.toString(), 
           getAdapterPosition());
                 }

                 /*int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
             String weatherForDay = mWeatherData[adapterPosition];
             mOnClickListener.onListItemClick(adapterPosition, 
                weatherForDay);*/
    }

}
    //interface is created to define a listener
    public interface ListItemClickListener {
        // we just need index of the click item so int variable is created
        void onListItemClick(String v, int position);
    }
```

}
here you can check and comment.
and onListItemClick(String v, int position) is sending to MainActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTag(value)` method in onBindViewHolder() and then you can retrieve the value using `getTag()`.

```
//set value
view.setTag(value);
//get value
String value = view.getTag().toString();
```

for more than one value:

```
//set values
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add("one");
values.add("two");
values.add("three");
view.setTag(values)

//get values
ArrayList<String> values = (ArrayList<String>) view.getTag();
```

Comment: can i use two or more tags?

Comment: setTag() takes Object as an argument. So, you can create List/Array/Pair and pass it.

Comment: please give some example

Comment: that  second example is not working. can you make it more clear. Because i want to use that tag value in different methods separately.

Comment: of course, you have to use them separately. set values in onBIndViewHolder and get values in onClick.

Comment: i mean to say that  i need id and textView value from tag  and use them separately.  And to add key in setTag() method int is required, isn't it? So how could i apply second example? explain please!

Answer (score 0):

You already call the `getAdapterPosition()` of RecyclerView.ViewHolder. This will return the position of the clicked item in your data collection. So you can use it to fetch the data.

Comment: how ? can you provide some example.

Comment: What is your underlying data structure?

Comment: three override method of 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ScannerListAdapter.ScannerViewHolder>   interface for onClickListener  and  this is implemented in MainActivity, that's it.

Comment: By underlying data structure, I mean what type of data structure do you use in the adapter? Is it a List, array or something else? What is your model object? Can you update your question with your MainActivity and ScannerListAdapter, please?

Comment: This is a simple RecyclerView example that I put together now. Please take a look as you might find it useful. https://gist.github.com/lastminute84/8590f38452ccaa758442f10bcc349f92

Comment: i  am fetching data from database .Therefore no list or array.

Comment: Would you update your question and include the code, please?

Comment: So your underlying data structure is a Cursor. You didn't include your MainActivity in your answer. But you need to call `cursor.moveToPosition(index)` in your `MainActivity.onListItemClick` method to get the value of the clicked item.